# Work-hours problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

4 people work for 4 hours per day and complete a job in 4 days.

If 8 people work for 8 hours per day, how many days does it take for the job to be completed?

Comment: The job appears to take 64 man-hours, so in theory 8 men at 8 hours a day take 1 day. However, if one woman takes nine months to gestate a baby how long do two women take ? In the real world one should be careful how to apply calculations such as this !

Comment: @TomCollinge: How many *man*-hours does it take to gestate a baby?

Comment: @Vixen: about 10 minutes last time I was involved, depends whether you include dinner beforehand or not.

Answer (score 3):

The job requires $4\times 4\times 4=64$ manhours to complete, so it will be completed in $1$ day.